# Screen does not lock on suspend

Tags: suspend, screen, lock

I have recently updated to 20.04 and now when I suspend, either waiting for a long time, closing the lid or manually suspending, the screen does not automatically lock. I've tried setting the 'lock on suspend' in the setting but nothing changed.

I am running lightdm with unity greeter, if that helps.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242433/ubuntu-20-04-gnome3-lighdm-lock-screen-on-suspend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who has come looking for a solution to a similar problem, here's how I solved it.

Credit to pszafer here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191797

So it turns out that indeed it is due to lightdm that ubuntu was disabling the automatic lock. To get around thata I wrote the following script that calls dm-tool to lock the screen, saved in the home directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
export XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
dm-tool lock
```

Note that you `Seat0` might be different for you. You can check that by running

```
dm-tool list-seats
```

Then I put this script saved at `/etc/systemd/system/dmlock.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=DM Lock before sleep
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/path/to/previous/script

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Then you need to enable the service using

```
systemctl enable dmlock.service
```

You can also test if it is working with

```
systemctl start dmlock.service
```

Comment: Does the lock work, if you try different Ctrl-Alt-function keys?

Comment: @jarno you can set a custon short cut to rum dm-tool lock to lock the screen, but the usual lock screen short cuts are disabled by ubuntu when you use a different dm.

Comment: Nice workaround but lock screen really should be working correctly by default. I'm surprised its not fixed already!

Comment: Always remember to make the script executable with `chmod 755 /home/path/to/script/`. I forgot this myself at my first attempt :-).