# Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome3 / LighDM) > lock screen on suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lightdm, lock-screen

It might be a [duplicate] but none of the answers I found work for me.

```
brieucdug@sildenafil:~$ uname -a ; gnome-shell --version ; lightdm --version
Linux sildenafil 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GNOME Shell 3.36.2
lightdm 1.30.0
```

I don't know from when, I suspect it comes with the installation of `lightdm`, my screen doesn't lock with **timeout** nor on **suspend** (lid closed, this is how I first found out the issue). I confirm my computer does go in suspend when I close the lid.

```
brieucdug@sildenafil:~$ gsettings list-recursively  | grep -i -E "screen.*lock|lock.*screen"
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock false
org.gnome.desktop.privacy usb-protection-level 'lockscreen'
org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-in-lock-screen true
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 0
```

And a screen in my settings...
[image: screen lock settings]

NB : I already tried to edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but I am open to suggestions

Comment: I can confirm that my desktop rig has the same issues and I assume the reason is the lightdm. I use lightdm because multiseat with gdm3 was acting funny, and as soon as I installed (and used) lightdm, screensaving stopped working :( IIRC there was a popup message by Gnome warning me from that, but that popup disappeared quickly and I could not fully read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the following as `/etc/systemd/system/lock-on-wakeup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen when waking up
Before=sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=dm-tool lock ; sleep 2
Environment=XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

Then activate this with:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable lock-on-wakeup.service
```

`sleep 2` in `ExecStart=` should prevent the system to go to sleep before the lock screen activation is in effect (which would result in the user's desktop being visible for a split second after waking up, before the lock screen actually activates). If this is not sufficient, increase the value. (Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after any modifications.) There might be more proper solutions than sleep to make sure the lock screen is in effect.

Helpful resources were especially:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81694/59725
- https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/463#issuecomment-472666569

Answer (score 1):

I solved creating a service using `loginctl`:

Check if your system has `loginctl`:
`sudo /bin/loginctl lock-sessions`

1 - Create the file:
`sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/lock.service`

2 - Fill it with:

```
[Unit]
Description="Make extra sure to lock the screen when suspending"

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/loginctl lock-sessions

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

3 - Afterwards, type:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable lock.service
```

Here are more details on how to lock when suspend:
https://makandracards.com/makandra-orga/166759-ensure-screen-lock-on-suspend

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my screen wasn't locking at all, neither with super + L nor CLI options from [How do I lock the desktop screen via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7776/how-do-i-lock-the-desktop-screen-via-command-line) and then I managed to get super + L working as per [After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 Lockscreen not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242110/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-lockscreen-not-working) with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Once that was done, suspend would also lock the screen. This happened on Ubuntu 23.10, GDM display manager.